# Is it possible to add subscripts or superscripts into a legend?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography, legend

I have a population density map where I'm showing the amount of people per square kilometer. In order to make it more visually appealing I want to show something like:

- [any symbol here] - 2.00 - 5.00 people/km2 <--- where this 2 should be a superscript.

Is that possible in ArcMap? If so, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like 2.00 - 5.00 people/km<sup>2</sup> in the layer name or layer description will work just as well. the 2 is enclosed between Superscript tag

Read [this](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-text/formatting-tags-available-in-arcmap.htm) for more info about format tags available in ArcMap.

Answer (score 2):

Use the character map to copy and paste the super-script character. It's a Windows tool, just search for it. You can use this for all sorts of characters that have [Diacritic mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic)s.

Answer (score 2):

For example, if you want to write per km square.
Then - for superscript - `km<sup>2</sup>`
       for subscript-    `km<sub>2</sub>`